# PKPassLibrary.isPassLibraryAvailable returns true in ipad simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, passbook

When I run my app in ipad simulator `[PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable]` returns true. Is it expected?. I thought it will return true when passbook app exists.

Comment: Yes, you're right it does!  Looks like it could be a bug as it returns false on the device.

Comment: @PassKit. Are you sure it returns false on the iPad if your app is not universal?.

Comment: No, For ipad simulator its coming false. I checked like if (![PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable]).

Comment: it returns false for me. What version of ios are you using?. I tried in ios6.1

Comment: Checked before leaving the office iOS 6.1.4 on latest Xcode.  Wondering if it could be iCloud related, but iPad sim was definitely positive.

Comment: @PassKit, I have trouble with iPad device as well. I added another check for iPad to get around the situation. Its isn't clean.